# If Lie algebra is equal to its commutant, is it semisimple?

Tags: lie-algebras

I am searching for a prove or a counterexample for this statement:

*If finite-dimensional complex Lie algebra is equal to its commutant, then it is semisimple.*

I suppose it is not true, because otherwise I would be able to find this beautiful result somewhere.

Comment: No, it is strictly weaker property. If Lie algebra is equal to its commutant, it is called perfect. Here is a counterexample: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60498/lie-algebra-semisimple

Comment: @rafaelm Converted to an answer as it's been over 10 minutes. Let me know if you want me to delete.

Comment: Well, I can confirm that the $10$ minutes are over now, after $9$ years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is a strictly weaker property. If Lie algebra is equal to its commutant, it is called perfect. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60498/lie-algebra-semisimple) for a counterexample.

Comment: Alas, I can not ask it there, on the page of answer. I do not understand why the mentioned operation satisfies Jacobi identity: $[[(X,v),(Y,u)],(Z,w)] = [([X,Y],Xu-Yv),(Z,w)]=([[X,Y],Z], [X,Y]w-Z(Xu-Yv))=([[X,Y],Z], [Y,Z]v+[Z,X]u+[X,Y]w)$, but the sum of three summand like this one will not be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Nonsemisimple perfect Lie algebras arise when contracting, or degenerating semisimple Lie algebras. A well-known example in physics is that the semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ (the de Sitter Lie algebra) contracts to the Poincaré Lie algebra, which is perfect, but not semisimple. Of course, this Lie algebra is just $\mathbb{R}\rtimes \mathfrak{so}(3,1)$.